# How to navigate in a Dired buffer?

Tags: dired, motion

window 10, Emacs 26.1, Dired+

Suppose I open in Dired+ mode some folder:

```
d:/TEMP/test_folder/folder2/
```

[image]

I need next:

1. When press button "**End**" then go to the last file in the folder. Like this:

[image]

2. When press button "**Home**" then go to the first file in the folder. Like this:
   [image]
3. When press button "**Backspace**" then go to the up folder. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.

```elisp
(defun my/dired-last-file ()
  (interactive)
  (end-of-buffer)
  (dired-next-line -1))
```

2.

```elisp
(defun my/dired-first-file ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (while (and (not (eobp))
              (or (bolp)
                  (member (dired-get-filename 'no-dir t)
                          '("." ".."))))
    (dired-next-line 1)))
```

3. Bind `<backspace>` to `dired-up-directory`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), Menu-bar menu **Dir**, submenu **Navigation** has these items, with associated keyboard keys:

- **Next Dirline** (**`>`**)
- **Prev Dirline** (**`<`**)
- **Next Subdir** (**`C-M-n`**)
- **Prev Subdir** (**`C-M-p`**)
- **Up Directory** (**`^`**)
- **Tree Up** (**`C-M-u`**)
- **Tree Down** (**`C-M-d`**)
- **Move To This Subdir** (**`i`**)

`C-M-u` and `C-M-d` are the same in vanilla Dired.  Vanilla Dired also offers (less useful) versions of `^`, `i` and `C-M-p`.

- For your #1, just use `M-> p`.  Or, if by "the folder" you mean the current subdir, use `C-M-n p p`.
- For your #2, you can use `M-< n`, repeating `n` as needed.  Or, if by "the folder" you mean the current subdir, use `C-M-p n`, repeating `n` as needed.
- For your #3, use `C-M-p`, possibly repeated.

Comment: "M -> p" - is not too comfortable combination. I need only press "End" button to go for first file in folder

Comment: 1. `M-> p` takes you to the last, not the first, file. (`M-< n` takes you to the first.) 2. You can bind what it does to any key you like, of course. 3. I think it's not very often that someone wants to go to the last file in a folder (and `M->` is well known as moving to the buffer end).